# SQL Server 2005 Single Quoted list of strings fail

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have an SP that has an `nvarchar(max)` parameter `@p1`. This is a comma separated list of codes e.g. `100,200,300` etc

Inside the SP I declare a variable `@p2 nvarchar(max)` and convert the `@p1` list into a single quoted list

```
set @p2 = N'''' + replace(@p1,',',''',''') + ''''
```

When I "select" `@p2` this returns the correct `'100', '200', '300'`

If I then use `@p2` in a subselect, e.g

```
select x,y,z from table1 where id in (@p2)
```

I get no rows returned? If I modify the same SQL to use the same string literal I got from the previous select I get the rows ok?

How can I pass a string containing a list of single quoted identifiers to a SP and use this in a subselect? I've Googled this extensively, and it is possible to convert the list to a temporary table inside the SP and use this, but I need to use the quoted list so I can use an OPTIMIZE FOR query hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IN` does not work with comma-separated strings the way you expect: it is considered a single string, not an implicit array of values.

`id IN ('101,102,103')` will only match if `id` is exact string `'101,102,103'`, not any of its individual separated chunks.

You should implement a [`TVF` which splits the string](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlgetstarted/thread/af334da4-3288-45c7-9334-d7119f631dad) and returns a set of its members and use it like that:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table1
WHERE   id IN
        (
        SELECT  value
        FROM    tvf_split_string('101,102,103')
        )
```

Comment: Great. Right. I see where you're coming from. I'll have a go a this and get back. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As Quassnoi says, you should use a function to split the string. Here's one that I use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tvf_split_string
(
    @List nvarchar(2000),
    @SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)  
RETURNS @RtnValue table 
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Value nvarchar(100)
) 
AS  
BEGIN 
    while (Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)>0)
    begin
        insert into @RtnValue (value)
        select 
            Value = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)-1)))

        set @List = Substring(@List,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)+len(@SplitOn),len(@List))
    end
    insert Into @RtnValue (Value)
    select Value = ltrim(rtrim(@List))

    return
END
```

And call it as follows:

> SELECT value FROM
>   dbo.tvf_split_string('101,102,103')

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use execute

```
Execute('select x,y,z from #1 where id in (' + @p2 + ')')
```